# Redirect logged in users to home page when trying to access login page

Tags: symfony

I am trying to make my Symfony2 website redirect logged in users to another page when trying to access the login page.

This is my security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Cocoa\LoginBundle\Entity\User: 
        algorithm:        sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: CocoaLoginBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/administration
        form_login:
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_check
        logout:
            path:   /administration/logout
            invalidate_session: true
            target: /


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/administration, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And this is my controller:

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

  public function loginAction() {
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('public_homepage'));
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
      $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
      $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
      $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('CocoaLoginBundle:Login:login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error' => $error));
  }

  public function loginCheckAction() {

  }

}
```

If I access the login page as anonymous user I do see the login form. But after I log in and load the login page I get a 500 server error:

```
The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.
```

A proposed fix I read in another topic is to put the login page behind a firewall. I did that but still error 500.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have only IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY role for path ^/login set in security.yml. So then there is no authentication token allowed to be passed to LoginController.

You should try either to add ROLE_ADMIN also for ^/login path in the access_control, or include ^/login under ^/administration so it will become ^/administration/login.

And as condition in LoginController you should try to use

```
if($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('public_homepage'));
}
```